# How to perform multiple math operations to derive new column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
consumer_id      order_total
1                    5
2                    6
3                    7
1                    5
```

For every consumer `consumer_id` I want to take the average of all the `order_total` per `consumer_id` and create a new column `SID` based on following rules:

```
if new `order_total` >= 7:
      SID = 3
elif new `order_total` >= 6 OR <7:
      SID = 2
else:
      SID = 1
```

new df should look like this (`consumer_id` 1, average is 5) :

```
consumer_id      order_total   SID
1                    5          1
2                    6          2
3                    7          3
1                    5          1
```

This is the if statement I tried without the average per `consumer_id`:

```
if df.order_total >= 150:
    df['SID'] = 3
elif [df.order >= 50] & [df.order< 100]:
    df['SID'] = 2
else:
    df['SID'] = 1
```

I get error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `apply`, use `np.select`:

```
s = df.groupby('consumer_id').order_total.transform('mean')

c1 = s.ge(7)
c2 = s.ge(6) & s.lt(7)

df.assign(SID=np.select([c1, c2], [3, 2], 1))
```

```
   consumer_id  order_total  SID
0            1            5    1
1            2            6    2
2            3            7    3
3            1            5    1
```

Answer (score 1):

try `apply`:

```
def f(x):
    if x >= 7:
        SID = 3
    elif x >= 6 and x<7:
        SID = 2
    else:
        SID = 1
    return SID

df['SID']=df['order_total'].apply(f)
```

Comment: Thank you for the post, this doesnt average the order total per consumer_id or does it?

Comment: @RustyShackleford It does, No?

Comment: not sure where in the code, it is considering every consumer_ID and averaging the results

Comment: @RustyShackleford Edited mine

Comment: testing one sec

Comment: @RustyShackleford Happy that i could help, it works, Hope well for you,

Comment: this is running the function on only the order total column values, not the average of the orders per consumer_id, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use groupby with transform to get a series containing the average order
total per consumer_id, then apply a function to the series to create the result series.

```
def sid_assign(x):
    if x >= 7:
        return 3
    if x >= 6 | x < 7:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

id_sums = df.groupby('consumer_id').order_total.transform('mean')
df['SID'] = id_sums.apply(sid_assign)

print(df)

   consumer_id  order_total  SID
0            1            5    1
1            2            6    2
2            3            7    3
3            1            5    1
```